# How to make `<tr>` accessible by keyboard (no javascript)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, accessibility

*Context:  I'm using bootstrap 4.1 in a vue.js app.*

I have a table that shows the results of a user performed search.

The users are able to "see mode details" by clicking on any row of this results table. So far so good with the mouse.

How do I make the same table accessible with the keyboard?

Expected outcome:

1. users perform a search
2. the data is shown in the table
3. by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> they focus the `<table>`
4. *(the "current row" gets highlighted)*
5. by hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> they are able to "see more details" of the given highlighted row

**Questions:**

- Is there a browser-native way to achieve this?
- Is there a way to do it without javascript?

---

---

So far:
[image]

This is done by using a `<table>` element with `tabindex="0"` on each `<tr>` element.
I'm now adding some javascript magic to make the click/enter user interaction trigger to show more details in another div.
Thanks all for the help.

Comment: encapsulate each result in a <a></a> - it will go into the natural tabindex, and you can adjust order by setting tabindex

Comment: I can't wrap each `<tr>` of the table with an anchor. It will break the table.   :/

Comment: The short answer is: you need javascript. Vue js should actually help you here. You *may* be able to hack something together with **CSS Tables** (not HTML tables) using `<a></a>` as `table-row` .....maybe

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

This is about as close as I think you can get without javascript.

You need to use css tables and not HTML tables and set the `a` tag as a `table-row`. Then set the "href" of the `a` tag to a hidden div with the more info. Use the `:target` psuedo class to make the hidden info visible.

You can now <kbd>tab</kbd> through the rows. However you need to press <kbd>Return</kbd> to activate the link (at least in Chrome)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table>.head,
.table>a {
  display: table-row;
}

.table>.head>span,
.table>a>span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

.table>a:focus {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.moreInfo>div {
  display: none;
}

.moreInfo>div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="head">
    <span>Id</span>
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Date</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#data1">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>Some Name</span>
    <span>9 Jan 2019</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#data2">
    <span>2</span>
    <span>Another Name</span>
    <span>10 Jan 2019</span>
  </a>

</div>
<div class="moreInfo">
  <div id="data1">Some more info on the first item</div>
  <div id="data2">Some more info on the second item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this one. And since I understand there is no a straight-forward way to do it in a native way I may think to also inject some javascript in there. Thanks  :)

Comment: The CSS solution is rudimentary at best, JavaScript would make it a LOT better.

Comment: good or bad as this is, doing it in CSS is a LOT better ! - bootstrap would have handled it too - good answer

Comment: @Adriano, since you marked your OP with the `accessibility` tag, I presume accessibility is important to you. This solution, while creative, will be totally unusable for a screen reader user. Visually, you have a table of information with column headers, but the above example does not use any table semantics. If native <table> elements are not used, then you need to supplement the code with ARIA roles. `role="table"` on the first <div>, each <a> needs a <div> container with `role="row"`, and another <div> or <span> with `role="cell"`.  Also `role="columnheader"` for ID/NAME.

Comment: @Adriano I concur with slugolicious. I don't see how a screen reader is going to understand that this is a table because it does not use table markup. Some screen readers switch to table navigation mode when they encounter table markup. They don't do that when they encounter some nested div and span elements.

Comment: Yep, I completely missed the `accessibility` tag. ARIA roles might help. Perhaps the best `accessible` option is a `table` with a "more information" link in a cell as the final column. If desired that column could be set to `display:none` using media queries when displayed on screen, but rendered normally for  screen readers.

Comment: @slugolicious I checked Jon P answer as correct because it was "technically" correct even though it doesn't allow high accessibility (or any, perhaps).     
Have a look at the bottom part of my question, I have implemented a combination of Jon P's response and the `<table>` element, and it works good enough. 
I still need to use some javascript in order to allow for navigation with the ARROW KEYS, but I believe with a `method()` in vue I will be able to achieve that.        :)

Comment: @Jon P - using `display:none` will prevent content from being passed to a screen reader.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the CSS solution won't be accessible.

In fact the CSS solution is even probably going to make the accessibility less good compared to if you have been used a `<table>` even without any JavaScript or ARIA.

If you really can't use JavaScript for whatever reason, I would still advice to keep the `<table>`

If the data presented is really tabular data, screen reader users won't understand anything if you don't use a true `<table>`.

Some screen readers try to present CSS tables like if they were true HTML tables, but often they fail in doing it really well, and many screen readers don't do anything special so the user see a serie of divs and spans.

Additionally, keyboard and screen reader users are used to:
- tab once to get into the table, tab once more to get out of it
- up/down arrow to move from row to row inside the table
- left/right arrow to move between columns if it's relevant in your case

IF you really want something accessible, that's what you need to do. And it's perfectly undoable without JavaScript.

Why don't you  want use JavaScript ?

Comment: Thanks for your point, and yes, I care about accessibility. have a look at the file I've attached to the question. That's where I am so far.

Comment: Sorry but I find "The CSS solution is a pure joke" quite insulting. Can't argue the accessibility statement though. However this reads more like an extended comment and not an actual answer.

Comment: Hi QuentinC, can you also expand a little what you mean with `And it's perfectly undoable without JavaScript.`? I would appreciate that :)

Comment: Jon P: Mozahler: You are perhaps true that this is an extended comment, but in a comment as far as I know, I can't be so long.
However, the question still includes the a11y tag, so you must be aware that without JavaScript there is no really accessible solution. Or the question isn't related to a11y, in which case you should perhaps remove the tag.

Adriano: I don't see what else to add. You simply can't do what I say without JavaScript.

Jon P: Sorry, I will reformulate.

Comment: Additionally, in a comment, paragraphs are totally removed. Sorry for that

Comment: @QuentinC - "keyboard and screen reader users are used to:" is a bit misleading. The behaviour you describe is what you get when _operating a screen reader, using a keyboard_. Keyboard users without a screen reader don't get this behaviour with a HTML table. It might be better to re-phrase this along the lines of "screen readers provide tools to interact with tables:"

Comment: @andrewmacpherson: In fact when I posted, I thought about a table designed as a multicolumn list where you can interact with the indifidual rows, such as those you can find for an e-mail or file list. I assumed that's what the asker were more or less going to do given his question. You are right, it's perhaps unclear. I'll see what I could do to clarify.

Comment: @QuentinC - aha, that sounds more like the ARIA grid pattern. It has different semantics to a table, but it may be appropriate for Adriano's design, sure enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can not imagine another way without using javascript! Here is the answer to your question!

You have to use *tabindex = "0"*. But to focus you would have to use javascript

```html
<div>
<a href="#" tabindex="0">
      <p>hi</p>
</a>
<a href="#">
   <p>hello</p>
</a>
<a href="#">
   <p>woah</p>
</a>
<a href="#">
   <p>oops</p>
</a>
<a href="#">
   <p>Love</p>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabindex for the table, it works perfectly fine

```
<form>
  First: <input tabindex="1" type="text">
  Third: <input tabindex="3" type="text"> <br>
  Second : <input tabindex="2" type="text">
  Forth : <input tabindex="4" type="text"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Ack!  Please don't use positive values for `tabindex`.  It makes the tabbing order all wonky.  From an accessibility perspective, the only values you should use for `tabindex` are 0 and -1.